# Solving $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So we have the following improper integral and we have to prove that it converges(if it converges then find its value). $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^2}dx$$

I tried the feynman approach of letting $f(a)$ as:
$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)(1-\cos(ax))}{x^2}dx$$
$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)-\sin(2ax)/2}{x^2}dx$$
Differentiating twice, wrt $a$:
$$f''(a)=-\int_0^\infty \sin(ax)-2\sin(2ax)dx$$
But then I run into a trap because of limits, I have to let $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\cos(ax))=\alpha;\,\,\,[-1<\alpha<1]$, but it is fruitless, and I can't solve it further. So I need help after this stage or could anyone suggest a better method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help that by the double-angle identities, $\sin(x)[1-\cos(x)] = 2\sin(x)\sin^2(x/2) = 4 \sin^3(x/2)\cos(x/2)$.

Comment: Integrate by parts and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2099677)

Comment: I think after using the double angle identities, series expansion and Ramanujan's master theorem works.

Comment: Substituting $x\rightarrow 2u$ lets you write it as $\int_0^\infty \sin(2u)[\sin(u)/u]^2 dx$, which is so close to being the Fourier transform of the triangle function.

Comment: Your integral is a special case of the one in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643989/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sinxt1-cosatt2-dt?rq=1.

Answer (score 12):

We can rewrite as
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(x)}(1 - \cos{(x)})}{x^{2}} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x} - \frac{\sin{2x}}{2x}\right)\frac{1}{x}\ dx$$
This is of the form of a [Frullani Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) where $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x = 0$. We have that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\infty) = 0$. Then,
$$I = (f(\infty) - f(0))\ln\frac{1}{2} = (0 - 1)\ln\frac{1}{2} = \ln{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following property
$$ \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(x) g(x)\;dx=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(x) f(x)\;dx $$
to get the integral.
In fact, noting
$$ \mathcal{L}\{t\}(x)=\frac1{x^2}$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(x)}(1 - \cos{(x)})}{x^{2}} \ dx \\
&=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(x)}(1 - \cos{(x)})\mathcal{L}\{t\}(x)\; dx\\
&=& \int_{0}^{\infty}x\mathcal{L}\{\sin{(t)}(1 - \cos{(t)})\}(x)\; dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}\; dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3}{(x+1)(x+4)}\; dx\\
&=&\frac12\ln\bigg(\frac{x+1}{x+4}\bigg)\bigg|_0^\infty\\
&=&\ln2.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts gives $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\int_0^{\infty} \sin x(1-\cos x) d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
& =-  \underbrace{ \left[\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x}\right]_0^{\infty}}_{=0} +\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x-\cos (2 x)}{x}dx
\end{aligned}
$$
Considering the parameterized integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x-\cos (2 x)}{x} e^{-a x} d x
$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =-\int_0^{\infty} \cos x e^{-a x} d x+\int_0^{\infty} \cos (2 x) e^{-a x} d x \\
& =-\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{a}{a^2+4}
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating $I’(a) $ from $a=0$ to $\infty$ gives
$$
I(\infty)-I(0)=\int_0^{\infty}\left(-\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{a}{a^2+4}\right) d a=-\ln 2
$$
Hence
$$I=I(0)=\ln 2$$

Comment: How did you do the third to last step when the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\cos{yx}$ does not exist ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I’ll fix it later.

Comment: Still, the limit does not exist. $e^{-yix}$ oscillates as $x$ increases. It keeps going around and around on the unit circle as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @conan, thank you again.  Fixed it.